# SQL Select statement using array values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to SELECT based on the values in one of my array key fields.

I have seen a few similar questions which were answered using a join but this didn't quite work for me.

Here's what I have so far;

```
$sku = join("','", $itemrow["SellerSKU"]);
$item_id =("SELECT PRODUCT_ID FROM ".DB_PRODUCTS." WHERE PRODUCT_CODE = ($sku);");
```

The error I'm getting is:

**Warning**:  join(): Invalid arguments passed

SOLVED::
In addition to the accepted answer this also worked;

I also managed this by re-jigging the statement and concatenating the variable; ("SELECT PRODUCT_ID FROM ".DB_PRODUCTS." WHERE PRODUCT_CODE = ".$itemrow["SellerSKU"].";

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, you `IN` and `implode`

Try this-

```
$query= "SELECT PRODUCT_ID FROM ".DB_PRODUCTS." WHERE PRODUCT_CODE IN (" . implode(',', $itemrow["SellerSKU"]) . ")";
```

Comment: `"...IN (" . implode(',', $itemrow["SellerSKU"]) . ")";`

Comment: Worked using hjpotter92's solution! Will accept as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sku = implode(",", $itemrow["SellerSKU"]);
$item_id =("SELECT PRODUCT_ID FROM ".DB_PRODUCTS." WHERE PRODUCT_CODE in ($sku);");
```